# Why does deleteObject: cause CoreData faults?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a cleanup routine that purges out a bunch of managed objects, form some reason that seems to trigger a lot of CoreData faults.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"LogEvent"];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"id" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
[request setFetchLimit:numberToPurge];

NSArray *events = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

for (LogEvent *event in events) {
    [context deleteObject:event];
}

[context save:nil];
```

This is what I see in instruments.

[image: CoreData faulting with deleteObject]

Comment: I'm not sure why but you could optimize with propertysToFetch empty array and returnAsFaults NO.

Answer (score 0):

This faults are usually fired to update inverse relationships on objects that was linked to deleted objects.

Comment: This object has no relationships though so that can't be the reason.

Comment: Try to set `includesPropertyValues` to `NO`.